# AWS Firehose : The response received from the endpoint is invalid

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am trying to send response from AWS lambda to AWS kinesis but I got this message :

```
{
  "attemptsMade": 8,
  "arrivalTimestamp": 1616435162190,
  "errorCode": "HttpEndpoint.InvalidResponseFromDestination",
  "errorMessage": "The response received from the endpoint is invalid. See Troubleshooting HTTP Endpoints in the Firehose documentation for more information. Reason:. Response for request ec3a4878-726d-45df-a494-f200573c7067 must contain a 'content-type: application/json' header. Raw response received: 502: <html>\r\n<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>\r\n<body>\r\n<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>",
  "attemptEndingTimestamp": 1616435539614
}
```

My response :

```
{
    "headers": {
        "content-length": 1024,
        "content-type": "application/json"
    },
    "body": {
        "requestId": "136805ed-6702-4bac-806c-4be5dc025715",
        "timestamp": 1616433644511
    },
    "statusCode": 200
}
```

My code to take the send the output stream after getting it from kineses :

```
public void serialize(OutputStream outputStream, RecordsData recordsData) throws IOException {

    JSONObject headerJson = new JSONObject();
    headerJson.put("Content-Type", "application/json");

    JSONObject responseBody = new JSONObject();
    responseBody.put("requestId", recordsData.getRequestId());
    responseBody.put("timestamp", new Date().getTime());

    JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject();
    responseJson.put("statusCode", 200);
    responseJson.put("body", responseBody);
    responseJson.put("headers", headerJson);
    responseJson.put("isBase64Encoded", true);

    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8");
    writer.write(responseJson.toString());
    writer.close();

}
```

Comment: Please give more information such as your code. Also double-check if your lambda has permission to push to kinesis, the regions are correct etc.

Comment: @PraneethPeiris it has full access and we use region us-east-1, I added my code

Comment: Side note: Why are you setting `responseJson.put("isBase64Encoded", true);` when your body is NOT base64 encoded?

Comment: @PraneethPeiris I removed this from the request but I still have the issue, I dont know what is the right response should I return

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if your code pushes messages to Kinesis in the correct way. Please check the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/developing-producers-with-sdk.html) and see if you're doing it right.